# How to nest if-else inside an if in JSX syntax using ternary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to achieve the following in JSX:

```
if (declineButtonMessage) {
    if (buttonDirection === 'column') {
        render button 1
    } else {
        render button 2
    }
}
```

I have this so far:

```
{declineButtonMessage && (
    
)}
```

And I tried smuggling this inside:

```
buttonDirection === 'column' ? <StyledDeclineButton buttonDirection={buttonDirection} title={declineButtonMessage} wide onPress={onSecondaryAction} /> : <SecondaryButton buttonDirection={buttonDirection} title={declineButtonMessage} wide onPress={onSecondaryAction} />
```

But it wasn't working and my linter was going wild. I imagine I'm doing some sort of JSX syntax error

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
{
  declineButtonMessage 
    ? (buttonDirection === 'column' ? <button1 /> : <button2 />)
    : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{!!declineButtonMessage && (buttonDirection === 'column' ? <button1 /> : <button2 />)}
```

Try this pls

Comment: Why would you twice negate the declineButtonMessage  though?

Comment: because of avascript truthy and falsy values.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy